# script to regularly download a csv file from a webpage that uses php

Tags: php

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I want to write a script (can be bash, python etc) that can automatically download a csv file from a webpage that is using PHP (which I know nothing about).  The web page is a regional weather service : http://www.meteo.fvg.it/archivio.php?ln=&p=dati 
and normally I get the CSV file by manually clicking on a station from the drop down bar, clicking "daily", clicking "visualize data" and then finally clicking "download CSV"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website sends an ajax POST request to http://www.meteo.fvg.it/ajax/getStationData.php with the following formfields:

```
a: 2018
m: 8
g: 4
s: CMT@Camino@syn@45.920300@12.938600@30
t: H_2
ln: 
o: visualizza
```

and returns a html page, where the downloadable CSV data is weirdly encoded directly into the href attribute of the download button:

```
<a href=\"data:application\/csv;charset=utf-8,giorno%3Bora%20UTC%2A%3BPioggia%20mm%3BTemp.%20gradi%20C%3BUmidita%27%20%25%3BVento%20med%20km%2...">
```

So in order to solve that programmatically, you have to check out the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools and get familiar with the fields and their params, that get sent along with the ajax request.
Then use curl to grab the result, like this (just copied out of the network tab) [Info](https://www.alexkras.com/copy-any-api-call-as-curl-request-with-chrome-developer-tools/)

```
curl 'http://www.meteo.fvg.it/ajax/getStationData.php' -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=olng2rqoia3qsecangkh3bg4r4' -H 'Origin: http://www.meteo.fvg.it' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,de;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.23 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H 'Referer: http://www.meteo.fvg.it/archivio.php?ln=&p=dati' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' --data 'a=2018&m=8&g=4&s=CMT%40Camino%40syn%4045.920300%4012.938600%4030&t=H_2&ln=&o=visualizza' --compressed
```

and then parse the result with a dom parser, to grab the content of the download button

and then url_decode that and save it.

You could use php, python, node.js for that - what ever you are more familiar with.

maybe, if you snoop around a bit more, you'll find a static url that gives you the result directly.

Answer (score 1):

Look where the file is downloaded from (eg Network-Console in  Browser) or your download source. Then use `file_get_contents` in php to download.

If the filename changes, try to find out the pattern. Maybe its just a date.